# How to send alert when Azure Service fabric health goes bad

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Recently the our Azure service fabric health went bad after a deployment. The deployment was successful but service fabric health went bad due to some code issue and it was not rolling back. Only on looking into the service fabric explorer did we know that the cluster went bad

Is there a way to get an email alert when the service fabric health goes bad.

Scenarios where service fabric failed
Whole cluster so what happened was 1 service went bad(showed in red) and was consuming a lot of memory and that in turn caused other services to go bad. after which the whole cluster I had to log into the scaleset to see which services was taking most of the memory.

In another case we added another reliable collection to existing reliable collection to statefull service. This caused failure.

in each of the cases i need to look at the servifabric explorer and then go to each scale set to see the actual error message.

Comment: What exactly went has, a single service or the whole cluster.

Comment: updated above scenarios but it would be both where a single service goes bad and that in turn the whole cluster over all health.

Comment: Maybe the watchdog service is something that you are looking for: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/softwaresimian/2017/09/18/service-fabric-watchdog-connector/